# How can i Combine Tweet Feeds into One and arrange it by Time/Date using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can i Combine Tweet Feeds into One and arrange it by Time/Date using Javascript? or any options that you can give. Thank you.

```
// i get the Tweets with these code: but how am i able to combine these tweets into one and // arrange them to date??
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    getTwitters('tweet', {
        id: '@user1', // for example, ours is 'wighthat'
        count: 5, // the number of tweets to display
        enableLinks: true, // if you wish to display links
        clearContents: true,
        ignoreReplies: true,
        template: '<img height="16" width="16" src="%user_profile_image_url%" /> <a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%">%user_name%</a> <b>said:</b>  <span class="status">"%text%"</span> <span class="time"><a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id_str%">%time%</a></span>'      
    });

    getTwitters ('tweet2', {
        id: '@user2', // for example, ours is 'wighthat'
    count: 5, // the number of tweets to display
    enableLinks: true, // if you wish to display links
    clearContents: true,
    ignoreReplies: true,
    template: '<img height="16" width="16" src="%user_profile_image_url%" /> <a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%">%user_name%</a> <b>said:</b>  <span class="status">"%text%"</span> <span class="time"><a href="http://twitter.com/%user_screen_name%/statuses/%id_str%">%time%</a></span>'    
    });
 </script>
</head>
....
<body>
//these are how i get the tweets with different user in separate <div>
i wanted to put another div  with the combined Tweets of Both, any option?
 <table>
            <td>
    <div id="tweet" style="overflow: auto; height: 308px; width: 161px;">
    <p>Please wait while my Tweets load</p>
        <img src="../icons/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
      </td>
            <td>
        <div id="tweet2" ...> </td>                
</body>
```

i wanted to put another div  with the combined Tweets of Both, any option?

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle with whatever the things you done so far

Comment: Thanks, Chamika, but i got my answer on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917445/ajax-and-variable-scope